# Java Generics with existing classes

Tags: java, generics

I don't have an actual problem, I was just playing around with Java Generics and I realized that if I create a class with Generics, I can use any name for the generic part of the class (so inside the `<>`), it will be treated as a non-existing class, as a variable.

So if I use `String` as the generic part, it won't be `String` anymore, so for example you can't use its `charAt()` method.

I guess, this is a feature, because normally, if I know that I will want to use a `String` than I simply use it, and I don't create a generic class.

Am I right?

Comment: the meaning of a name in java highly depends on the context. In the same .java file, the same name can be used to mean different things. e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17690135/2158288

Comment: you can limit a generic type parameter to extend an existing type, in which case you could use methods for that type. is that what you mean?

Comment: That's because the name between the <> is just a name - the name of a type variable. Just like you can give regular variables the same name of a class. It's not a good idea to do that, because it's confusing.

Comment: yes, I know that, but from this answer I see that I understood the thing correctly, thanks

Comment: It's a good question, unfortunately [the JLS seems to be a bit unclear on this issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6972588). What is important to know though is the concepts of **shadowing** and **obscuring**, which is what you're witnessing in your example. And a type variable counts as a variable according to these rules.

Comment: java allows too much overloading of names, which seems useless, and causes bugs for new learners.

Comment: I think you are confused as to using a generic class vs creating one.  Look into the code behind a simple generic class and you will better understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use any classes with the same name if you use the full name including the package, e.g. `java.lang.String`.

The issue is actually the same as if you create a class named `String` in your package. You can do that, but then you also need do live with the consequences that classes in the same package will use this class instead of the standard String class.

Comment: The meaning of `java.lang.String` is also very ambiguous :) It could also mean variable access for example

Comment: @bayou.io Yes, it is relatively easy to create an example where there's no way to access something by either simple or qualified name.

Answer (score 1):

The generic allow us to use the single implementation with different type.

For example, consider the `collection framework` from java. The `List<T>` is a generic type you can create an `List` of any type in java. It provide you different useful operation which you can perform on different types like wrapper classes of primitive type.

If you use the generic for your custom type, then you might need to specify some implementation to support the generic functionality. **You can still use the general behavior of types as well**.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This is a list of type `String`. You can create any `List` like wise. Now you can use many functionality provided by java easily. Now if you need the same functionality for `Integer`, then you need to re-write the same.